# Javascript radio checkbox simple

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I have the following code that isnt telling the user the checkbox has to be clicked. Any help would be great!

```
function validate_form(){

valid=true;

var letters=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/;
var email=document.order_form.user_email.value;
var invalid = [];

if (email.indexOf("@")<1 || email.lastIndexOf(".")<email.indexOf("@")+2 
|| email.lastIndexOf(".")+2>=email.length){
invalid.push("*Email")
}

if (document.order_form.address.value.search(letters)==-1){
invalid.push("*Address")
}


if (document.order_form.drop_down.selectedIndex==false){
invalid.push("*Age")
}

if (document.order_form.sex.checked==false){
invalid.push("*Sex")
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="titles">*Sex:</div>

                <p>
                Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> 
                Female <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
                </p>


            </div>
```

It is really only the sex part I am trying to have validated! Everything else works fine!!!

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Make one selected by default, then you don't need to validate them. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector`, this way

```
if (!(document.querySelector('input[name="sex"]:checked')||{}).value) { /*...*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (document.order_form.sex[0].checked==false && 
      document.order_form.sex[1].checked==false){
    invalid.push("*Sex");
}
```